# what is the simplest way to recover profile information from orkut for a user (ideally oauth-like login)?

Tags: php, oauth, opensocial

There is a facebook api to recover information about the user, and maybe his friends list as well.

Just like that is there something like that for orkut? 
Hopefully, there will be a class or library written in php.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to direct you to the home of Google's Many APIs. Orkut is owned by Google, so you can find it at

http://code.google.com

The specific API you are looking for is

http://code.google.com/apis/orkut/

There you can find plenty of pre-made libraries in various languages (including PHP) that will allow you to access profile information.

One of Google's best features is its code.google.com site that provides a very good explanation of all the various APIs you can access on their properties.